# Find a specific record in Access and display the records into textboxes

Tags: c#

Hey Im new to stacoverflow and would like to ask some help. I need to type a ID into a textbox and when searched is clicked it will find the record and display each of the colum values to text boxes. Im using a access database. I have found solution on this but they dont seem to work. I have found and ajusted the following code but give an error op conn.open() and is coded in C#. Please help me.

source Code:

```
public partial class FamilyTree : UserControl
{
    private OleDbConnection conn;

    public FamilyTree()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FamilyTree_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Hannes\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fam\fam\Prog.mdb");
        conn.Open();
    }

    private void DisconnectDatabase()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = txtID.Text.ToString();
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM FamilyTree" + txtID ;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryString;
        command.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txtSex.Text += dr["gendre"].ToString();
            txtColour.Text += dr["name"].ToString();
            txtDOB.Text += dr["DOB"].ToString();
            txtStatus.Text += dr["city"].ToString();
            txtCock.Text += dr["mom"].ToString();
            txtHen.Text += dr["dad"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Which "error" (`Exception`) is thrown?
Your query string is wrong. -> SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value

Comment: `string queryString = "SELECT * FROM FamilyTree" + txtID ;` can you paste what the string looks like when you pass this line in the debugger..? it will not work just from looking at it.. you need a where clause... also where are you calling the method `ConnectToDatabBase` you cannot call open on a connection twice also consider wrapping the OleDbCommand, Connection, and Command Objects` around a using for auto disposing..`txtSex.Text += dr["gendre"].ToString();` why are you using `+=` are there going to be more than 1 row returned? if so create a Class and create a List<Class> to hold the data

Comment: It looks like you may have wanted to append title to the queryString assignment instead of using the txtId control and like @MethodMan says, it's missing the where clause.

Comment: also look at how to create a parameterized query to avoid potential SQL Injection [Basic Sql Tutorial for beginners](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) your select query should look like the following 
`var queryString = string.Format(SELECT * FROM FamilyTree WHERE ID = {0}", txtID.Text);` for example or google how to use command.Parameters.Add() method or  command.Parameters.AddWithValues() method

Comment: Once you get this to work, you may want to assign txtHen.Text = dr["mom"] and txtCock.Text = dr["dad"]. Otherwise the displayed results may be misleading. ;-)

Comment: another question, can you run the following query 
`SELECT * FROM FamilyTree WHERE ID = put value here that you know exist` also does it return multiple rows for example if ID=8 if so then you will need to also add conditional clause in your WHERE Clause, the reason I ask is because, you don't need `+=` unless you are wanting to display concat values.. does this make sense

Comment: Hey guys. I have made the changes and my Line : OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); is give the following error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the 'ConnectToDatabase()' method is called somewhere before using 'conn' in btnSearch_Click.

Next, decide whether you are using the Id or Title to filter the result.

When creating the queryString, ensure you use the 'WHERE Id = ' or 'WHERE Title = ' clause to filter - but also ensure that you have a space between the end of the queryString and the value added at the end - the example you have given would produce 'SELECT * FROM FamilyTree23' if the Id was 23. This would error because there is no table with this name in the database.

Finally, as mentioned in other answers, 'using' a database connection, and using query parameters are a better practice. The 'using' statement will release the connection automatically after use, and a parameterised query prevent will SQL Injection issues and ensure correct data types are passed to the query.

Example:

```
public partial class FamilyTree : UserControl
{
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Hannes\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fam\fam\Prog.mdb";

    public FamilyTree()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FamilyTree_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = txtID.Text.ToString();
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM FamilyTree WHERE Title = ?";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", title);
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    txtSex.Text += dr["gendre"].ToString();
                    txtColour.Text += dr["name"].ToString();
                    txtDOB.Text += dr["DOB"].ToString();
                    txtStatus.Text += dr["city"].ToString();
                    txtCock.Text += dr["mom"].ToString();
                    txtHen.Text += dr["dad"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey guys. I have made the changes and my Line : OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); is give the following error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Hi Johannes, this would mean that the 'title' variable in the example above has no value. Try hard-coding a value into the 'title' variable. If this works, then check what is coming back from your textbox on the page. It is most likely null or an empty string.